# снимок с web-камеры .JPG сохраняется с нулевым размером. Delphi + Web-камера

Tags: delphi, web-камера

Пишу приложение, оно должно сохранить фото в blob-поле, но это будет следующий шаг, а сейчас хочу получить снимок хотя бы в виде файла .jpg. Но вот как-то .bmp получаю, а вот .jpg ни как не могу, создаётся лишь файл с 0(ноль) байт.
Код кнопки сохранения фото с камеры:

```
procedure TForm1.Button14Click(Sender: TObject);
var

  jpgImg: TJPEGImage;

begin

 hWndC := capCreateCaptureWindowA('My Own Capture Window',
    WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE,
    Image1.Left,
    Image1.Top,
    Image1.Width,
    Image1.Height,
    Form1.Handle,
    0);
  if hWndC <> 0 then
    SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0); //"подключаемся" к веб-камере

  jpgImg := TJPEGImage.Create;

  jpgImg.Assign(image1.Picture.Bitmap);

  jpgImg.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'\tmp_0001.jpg');

  jpgImg.Free;

  SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);  //"отключаемся" от веб-камеры

  hWndC := 0;

end;
```

в `uses` `JPEG` подключен.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: `jpgImg.Assign(image1.Picture.Bitmap);` Ну а где в сам Image1.Picture.Bitmap что-нибудь записывается?

Comment: С чего вы взяли что bmp получаете? Он у вас сохраняется в файл? Есть мнение, что драйвер камеры рисует свою картинку поверх окна, хэндл которого она получила, но никак не в Image1.

Comment: @kami пробовал с BMP - там записывается. Мне кажется проблема в `jpgImg.Assign(image1.Picture.Bitmap)`

Answer (score 3):

Нужно передавать не `Form1.Handle`, а что-то типа `Image1.Canvas.Handle`. В вашем коде всё рисуется на канве формы, а сам Image остается пустым и прозрачным, поэтому "под ним" всё видно.

Upd. по комментарию kot-da-vinci:
Скорее всего, рисование картинки с камеры идет действительно поверх вашего окна. В этом случае даже захват канвы формы ничего не даст, поскольку де-факто рисуется на отдельном окне с применением аппаратного оверлея.
В этом случае вам может помочь [BitBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) с флагом CAPTUREBLT. С одним ограничением: CaptureBlt достаточно сильно замедляет оверлей (по крайней мере, так было во времена Windows XP).

Comment: действительно, что-то не то всё. Сделал `Image1.Canvas.Handle` приходит теперь белая картинка.

Comment: @I_CaR самое главное в моем ответе - дополнение по комментарию kot-da-vinci. Вы использовали BitBlt с указанным флагом?